# Can URLs be changed to add slugs after the site has been live?

Tags: seo, url, keywords, url-slug, url-keywords

We  have had a website for last 5 months but we did not use URL slugs on bottom level elements. Our URLs are like:

```
/apps/webmasters/badges/1100
```

would it make sense to add a name to the URL at this point and redirect to the new ones? I am interested in building more search terms and getting better rankings.

```
/apps/webmasters/badges/1100 -> redirect and served at 
/apps/webmasters/badges/1100-supporter
```

Or should I keep old URLs as is and create only new URLs with slugs? I would also appreciate some advice on URLs that have been shared on Facebook or on Twitter in those cases.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're adding useful keywords to your URLs, like the title of the page just like this website does, this can be beneficial for your rankings and would be worth doing. You'll want to do a 301 redirect from the old URL to the new URL to make sure both search engines and usersfind the new URLs and search engines can attribute links to the old URLs to the new URLs which is necessary to preserve whatever rankings your pages currently have.